# Loop to fill empty remaining space within a div

Tags: javascript

I am creating a battleship game for my next project to learn javascript and I am attempting to create divs to fill up a container `wrapper`. I do not want the divs to overflow, only to fill up the remaining space until it is filled. How do I test for the empty space remaining within a div to continue adding in my loop until the container is filled?

My container I am trying to fill is the `#wrapper`. My loop in javascript is creating the `divs`. I want to create a condition for the loop to stop filling when the container is full `(i = 0; i < ?; i++)`. How do I test for this?

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper')
const box = document.getElementsByClassName('.box');
const div = document.querySelector('div');

for (i = 0; i < 250; i++) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList = 'squares';
  wrapper.appendChild(div);
}

const destroyer1 = document.querySelector('#destroyer1');
const destroyer2 = document.querySelector('#destroyer2');

destroyer1.addEventListener("drag", function(event) {}, false);

destroyer1.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {}, false);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

h1 {
  color: white;
}

#messageBoard {
  color: white;
}

#shipContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15rem;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(41, 25, 25);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30rem;
  padding: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.squares {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 5%;
  height: 5%;
}

.destroyer {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.destroyerSquare {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>BattleShip!</h1>
<p id="messageBoard">Place Your Ships!</p>
</div>
<div id="shipContainer" draggable="true">
  <div class='destroyer' id='destroyer1'>
    <div class='destroyerSquare'></div>
    <div class='destroyerSquare'></div>
    <div class='destroyerSquare'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='destroyer' id='destroyer2'>
    <div class='destroyerSquare'></div>
    <div class='destroyerSquare'></div>
    <div class='destroyerSquare'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="battleship"></div>
  <div class="cruiser"></div>
  <div class="spyShip"></div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
</div>
```

Comment: I had made a working snippet out of your code, and you undid it?

Comment: Sorry I am new to stack overflow and was trying to figure out what that was. My apologies

Comment: No worries, let me do this again, and please don't destroy it :)

Comment: Just running the script tells you that you have an extra ot in `console.log(wrapper.)` that crashes the script

Comment: if the height of a square is 5% of wrapper you will need 20 of them with border and margin set to 0

Comment: I want it to completely fill up the container as much as possible regardless of size but not overflow.